# Generating pattern based on odd and even integers

Tags: python

I need help with converting my iterative code to recursive.

```
def pattern(int):
    if int == 0:
        return ''
    else:
        result = '*-'
            for i in range(int-1):
            if i%2 != 0:
                result += '*-'
            elif i % 2 == 0:
                result += '*--'
        return result
```

Above is the code I wrote to convert an integer into repetitive patterns. For int%2 != 0, it prints '*-' , and for int%2 == 0, it prints '*--'.

I have been stucked with converting the above to recursive. I understand the base case is '*-' with the terminating condition of int == 1. I should then concatenate the base case with pattern(int-1) recursively. Can anyone advise me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, Use:

```
def pattern(n):
    if n == 1: # Base case
        return "*-"

    if n % 2 == 0:
        return pattern(n - 1) + "*--"
    else:
        return pattern(n - 1) + "*-"
```

Calling the function:

```
print(pattern(10)) # builds the pattern corrensponding to integers from 1,2...10.
```

This prints:

```
*-*--*-*--*-*--*-*--*-*--
```